# Error: fs.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, browserify

I am trying to flash a hex file to an Arduino through a Chrome app I am making. I used basic NodeJS code, which is below, and converted it using browserify so that it would work in the browser. It doesn't work and I'm getting an error in the console saying 'TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function'

```
var Avrgirl = require('avrgirl-arduino');

var avrgirl = new Avrgirl({
  board: 'uno'
});

avrgirl.flash('Blink.cpp.hex', function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.info('done.');
  }
});
```

Comment: The `fs` module is not available in a browser.

Comment: Where am I using it?

Comment: Probably inside of `avrgirl.flash()` since you're passing it a filename.  You can't run this kind of code in a browser.  You should be running it in node.js.  browserify doesn't make magic happen for low level functionality that does not exist in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run this type of code in a browser (even with browserify).  You should be running it in node.js.

I would guess that your error is coming from inside of:

```
avrgirl.flash('Blink.cpp.hex', ...)
```

since you're passing a filename and that function is likely trying to read that file.

`browserify` cannot magically give a browser powers that it otherwise would not have such as reading files from your hard drive or communicating with arduino hardware.  This code was probably meant to be run in the node.js environment.

The [instructions](https://github.com/noopkat/avrgirl-arduino) for the `avrgirl-arduino` module, pretty clearly state you should be running in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but: Noopkat has made an avrgirl demo that uses webserial to flash board from the browser! Check it out. https://github.com/noopkat/avrgirl-arduino/tree/master/tests/demos/webserial